# Getting exact format with momentjs and lodash

Tags: javascript, momentjs, lodash

I have a list of times slots here eg:

```
const times = [
      { start: '2020-07-09T08:00:00.000+02:00', end: '2020-07-09T09:30:00.000+02:00' },
      { start: '2020-07-09T08:30:00.000+02:00', end: '2020-07-09T10:00:00.000+02:00' },
    ]
```

While I'm trying to **sort** them by day using momentjs and lodash to get something like:

```
{
        {startTime: '08:00', endTime: '08:30'}
        {startTime: '08:30', endTime: '09:00'}
        {startTime: '08:00', endTime: '08:30'}
        {startTime: '08:30', endTime: '09:00'}
    }
```

and I ended up with this solution for now:

```
const groupedAndFormatted = groupBy(times, date => moment(date.start_time).startOf('day').format('MMM Do YY'))
```

But this one didn't really give me the correct solution, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to sort them into the correct order, we will do this with sort and unix time stamps.

Then group them with the dddd

```
const times = [
  { start_time: '2020-07-09T08:00:00.000+02:00', endTime: '2020-07-09T09:30:00.000+02:00' },
  { start_time: '2020-07-09T08:30:00.000+02:00', endTime: '2020-07-09T10:00:00.000+02:00' },
  { start_time: '2020-07-07T09:00:00.000+02:00', endTime: '2020-07-07T10:30:00.000+02:00' }
];

const sorted_times = times.sort((a,b) => moment(a.start_time).unix() - moment(b.start_time).unix())
const grouped = _.groupBy(sorted_times, date => moment(date.start_time).format("dddd"))

const formatted = _.mapValues(grouped, dates => {
  return dates.map(times => {
    return {
      start_time: moment(times.start_time).format("hh:mma"),
      endTime: moment(times.endTime).format("hh:mma"),
    }
  })
})
```

However this will not work if you end up having multiple tuesdays on different dates.

Comment: Thank you Michael for your solution but it does not give me the dates in this format: startTime: '08:00' but instead it gives me the iso dates: startTime: '2020-07-09T08:00:00.000+02:00'

Comment: @Errand, updated. also side note, its odd you have snake case then camel case. for `start_time` and `endTime`